# How to make jquery plugin show up live? It only shows up locally

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins

I am currently developing a website that uses the ddslick jquery plugin. it allows for images to be alongside text on a drop down select menu. The issue is when I run it locally it works, but not when I upload it to my site on the web. I would like to know if anyone has experienced this error or has an idea on how I may fix this please? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ddslick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="register.css">
</head>
<body>


<section class="formRegister"  ng-app >
<form class="form-inline" name="formRegister" id="register" action="home.php" method="post" >
<h2> Register </h2>
 <p> Welcome  </p>
<p class="errorValidation" ng-show="formRegister.fullname.$invalid && formRegister.fullname.$touched">Please enter your name </p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="fullname"  placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="user.fullname" ng-required="true"> 
  </div> <br> <br>
  <p class="errorValidation" ng-show="formRegister.email.$invalid && formRegister.email.$touched">Please enter a valid email address </p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true">
  </div> <br> <br>
  <p class="errorValidation" ng-show="formRegister.passwordR.$invalid && formRegister.passwordR.$touched">Password must be at least 8 characters</p>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="initialPassword" name="passwordR"
   placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model= "user.password" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="8">
   </div> <br> <br>

   <div id="myDropdown"></div>
       <select id="schools">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="brown.gif"  data-description="Brown University">Brown University</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="dartmouth.gif"data-description="Dartmouth University">Dartmouth University</option>
        <option value="2" data-imagesrc="drexel.gif"data-description="Drexel University">Drexel University</option>
          <option value="3" data-imagesrc="georgemason.gif" data-description="George Mason University">George Mason University</option>
          <option value="4" data-imagesrc="georgiatech.gif" data-description="Georgia Tech">Georgia Institute of Technology</option>
        <option value="5" data-imagesrc="georgewashington.gif" data-description="George Washington University">George Washington University</option>
         <option value="6" data-imagesrc="georgetown.gif" data-description="George Town">George Town University</option>
        <option value="7" data-imagesrc="ncstate.gif" data-description="North Carolina State University">North Carolina State University</option>
        <option value="8" data-imagesrc="nyu.png" data-description="New York University">New York University</option>
        <option value="9" data-imagesrc="harvard.gif" data-description="Harvard University">Harvard University</option>
        <option value="10" data-imagesrc="northeastern.gif" data-description="Northeastern University">Northeastern University</option>
        <option value="11" data-imagesrc="ohiostate.gif" data-description="Ohio State University">Ohio State University</option>
        <option value="12" data-imagesrc="purdue.gif" data-description="Purdue University">Purdue University</option>
        <option value="13" data-imagesrc="townson.jpg" data-description="Townson University">Townson University</option>
        <option value="14" data-imagesrc="upenn.gif" data-description="University of Pennsylvania"> University of Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="15" data-imagesrc="utexasdallas.jpg" data-description="University of Texas - Dallas"> University of Texas - Dallas</option>
        <option value="16" data-imagesrc="uva.gif" data-description="University of Virginia">University of Virginia</option>
        <option value="17" data-imagesrc="sandiego.jpg" data-description="University fo San Diego"> University fo San Diego</option>
        <option value="18" data-imagesrc="vanderbilt.gif" data-description="Vanderbilt University">Vanderbilt University</option>
         <option value="19" data-imagesrc="vatech.gif" data-description=" Virginia Polytechinic Institute and State University">Virginia Polytechinic Institute and State University</option>
          <option value="20" data-imagesrc="yale.gif" data-description=" Yale University">Yale University</option> 

    </select>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
</form>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#schools').ddslick();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you uploading ddslick.js to the server?

Comment: In your root folder on the server I'm guessing you see ddslick.js, right?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ddslick.js"></script>
```

I assume you have this in the server...if not this is the issue and the other thing is you have to change the path to where its rooted correctly: `src="rootname/ifmorefolders/ddslick.js"`